# Multiple NVIDIA RTX GPU for Cuda (arch linux) with EGPU

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, gpu, cuda

I've got an **arch linux**, with two GPU in the laptop (**thinkpad P14s Gen 4**) + a new RTX 3090 plugged via thunderbolt 4 with the Cool Master EG200 GPU enclosure:

```
❯ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107GLM [RTX A500 Laptop GPU] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GA107GLM [RTX A500 Laptop GPU]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
22:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

The thunderbolt connection to the RTX 3090 is authorized as you can see here:

```
❯ sudo boltctl info c4010000-0070-740e-0362-00168691c921
[sudo] password for aemonge: 
 ● Cooler Master Technology,Inc MasterCase EG200
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          MasterCase EG200
   ├─ vendor:        Cooler Master Technology,Inc
   ├─ uuid:          c4010000-0070-740e-0362-00168691c921
   ├─ dbus path:     /org/freedesktop/bolt/devices/c4010000_0070_740e_0362_00168691c921
   ├─ generation:    Thunderbolt 3
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     69078780-60ab-fe2a-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  ├─ parent:     69078780-60ab-fe2a-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  ├─ syspath:    /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.2/domain0/0-0/0-1
   │  ├─ rx speed:   40 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 20 Gb/s
   │  ├─ tx speed:   40 Gb/s = 2 lanes * 20 Gb/s
   │  └─ authflags:  boot
   ├─ authorized:    Wed 24 Jan 2024 06:49:10 AM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Wed 24 Jan 2024 06:49:10 AM UTC
   └─ stored:        Tue 23 Jan 2024 03:50:50 PM UTC
      ├─ policy:     iommu
      └─ key:        no
```

I really don't care for the graphics, nor the RTX3090 to be loaded in the xorg nor the graphical interface. I just want it to be used as compute only workloads, and I have followed thouroly this arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/External_GPU

But givien that context, my `nvidia-smi` can't seam to find the GPU:

```
❯ nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: NVIDIA RTX A500 Laptop GPU (UUID: GPU-762410c2-1c0d-ef4a-89ac-91afd926381b)
```

Nor can a simple python script, **cuda-devices.py**:

```
❯ cat cuda-devics.py
import torch

# Check if CUDA is available
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("CUDA is available.")
    # Get the number of CUDA devices
    num_devices = torch.cuda.device_count()
    print(f"Number of CUDA devices: {num_devices}")
    # Get the name of each CUDA device
    for i in range(num_devices):
        print(f"Device {i} name: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(i)}")
else:
    print("CUDA is not available.")
❯ python cuda-devics.py
CUDA is available.
Number of CUDA devices: 1
Device 0 name: NVIDIA RTX A500 Laptop GPU

❯ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1,2" python cuda-devics.py

CUDA is available.
Number of CUDA devices: 1
Device 0 name: NVIDIA RTX A500 Laptop GPU
```

I have also tried with these three repositories https://github.com/ewagner12/all-ways-egpu ,  https://github.com/karli-sjoberg/gswitch and https://github.com/hertg/egpu-switcher. To disable the internal GPU's A500 and Iris Xe but it's blaking (black screen).

---

### Solved

Solved in https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/multiple-nvidia-rtx-gpu-for-cuda-arch-linux-with-egpu/280031/7 nvidia developer forums, by

> generic Top Contributor 5h

> Please check for a bios update. If none is available, please use Software & Updates to switch to the “-open” driver version and set kernel parameter nvidia.NVreg_OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus=1

Which meant the following:

```bash
sudo pacman -S nvidia-open
```

**/boot/loader/entries/*_linux.conf**

```
# Created by: archinstall
# Created on: ***********
title   Arch Linux (linux)
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /intel-ucode.img
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=PARTUUID=####-####-####### zswap.enabled=0 rw nvidia.NVreg_OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus=1 rootfstype=ext4
```

Comment: Please ask here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Done ;) https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/multiple-nvidia-rtx-gpu-for-cuda-arch-linux-with-egpu/280031

Comment: Read [NVIDIA Optimus](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/technologies/optimus/technology/) and please grep dmesg for `switcharoo`

Comment: I'm navigating through: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus but can't see the RTX 3090 either @eyoung100

Comment: Optimus is not card dependent, its a technology platform.  There are 2 possibilities here: The Laptops NVIDIA card is Discrete, meaning it does all the heavy lifting and passes the result to the intel card to draw, or it's soldered on.  Do you use the NVIDIA drivers, or have you switched to the `open version yet`?

Comment: I've just switched to the open version, and it's working.